# How to pass traceIds in Hystrix Observables?

Tags: rx-java, grpc, hystrix, grpc-java, zipkin

I have multiple services, some of which use Hystrix's HystrixObservableCommand to call other services and others use HystrixCommand. How do I pass on traceIds from the calling service to the Observables in HystrixObservableCommand and also have them be passed on if the fallback is called?

All services are using grpc-java.

Sample code that I have:

```
WorldCommand worldCommand = new WorldCommand(greeterRequest, worldServiceStub);
        String messageFromWorldService = "";
        String idFromWorldService = "";
        try {

            Greeter.GreeterReply greeterReply = worldCommand.construct().toBlocking().toFuture().get();
            messageFromWorldService = greeterReply.getMessage();
            idFromWorldService = greeterReply.getId();
            logger.info("Response from WorldService  -- {}, id = {}", messageFromWorldService, idFromWorldService);
        } catch (StatusRuntimeException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            logger.warn("Exception when calling WorldService\n" +  e);
        }
```

WorldCommand.java

```
public class WorldCommand extends HystrixObservableCommand<Greeter.GreeterReply> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorldCommand.class.getName());

    private final Greeter.GreeterRequest greeterRequest;
    private final WorldServiceGrpc.WorldServiceStub worldServiceStub;

    public WorldCommand(Greeter.GreeterRequest greeterRequest, WorldServiceGrpc.WorldServiceStub worldServiceStub) {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("WorldService"));
        this.greeterRequest = greeterRequest;
        this.worldServiceStub = worldServiceStub;
    }

    @Override
    protected Observable<Greeter.GreeterReply> construct() {
        Context context = Context.current();
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Greeter.GreeterReply>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Greeter.GreeterReply> observer) {
                logger.info("In WorldCommand");
                if (!observer.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    //pass on the context, if you want only certain headers to pass on then create a new Context and attach it.
                    context.attach();
                    logger.info("In WorldCommand after attach");
                    worldServiceStub.greetWithHelloOrWorld(greeterRequest, new StreamObserver<Greeter.GreeterReply>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Greeter.GreeterReply greeterReply) {
                            logger.info("Response from WorldService  -- {}, id = {}", greeterReply.getMessage(), greeterReply.getId());
                            observer.onNext(greeterReply);
                            observer.onCompleted();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            logger.info("Exception from WorldService  -- {}", t);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    @Override
    protected Observable<Greeter.GreeterReply> resumeWithFallback() {
        logger.info("Response from fallback");
        Greeter.GreeterReply greeterReply = Greeter.GreeterReply.newBuilder().setMessage("teammate").setId("-1").build();
        return Observable.just(greeterReply);
    }
```

I am using Zipkin grpc tracing and MDCCurrentTraceContext to print the traceId and spanId in the logs.

Both the log entries in the WorldCommand do not print out the trace and span ids, they are called on RxIoScheduler thread.

**EDIT**

Added ConcurrencyStrategy as suggested by Mike.

```
public class CustomHystrixConcurrencyStrategy extends HystrixConcurrencyStrategy {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomHystrixConcurrencyStrategy.class);

    public <T> Callable<T> wrapCallable(Callable<T> callable){
        log.info("In CustomHystrixConcurrencyStrategy: callable="+ callable.toString());
        return new ContextCallable<>(callable);
    }
}
```

HelloService calls two services World and Team. The WorldCommand is a HystrixObservableCommand, the TeamCommand is a HystrixCommand.

```
logger.info("In the HelloService:greetWithHelloWorld");
Greeter.GreeterRequest greeterRequest = Greeter.GreeterRequest.newBuilder().setId(request.getId()).build();

//Call WorldService
ManagedChannel worldChannel = getChannel("localhost:8081", "helloService-world-client");
//Async stub instead of blockingStub
WorldServiceGrpc.WorldServiceStub worldServiceStub = WorldServiceGrpc.newStub(worldChannel);

WorldCommand worldCommand = new WorldCommand(greeterRequest, worldServiceStub);
String messageFromWorldService = "";
String idFromWorldService = "";
try {

    Greeter.GreeterReply greeterReply = worldCommand.construct().toBlocking().toFuture().get();
    messageFromWorldService = greeterReply.getMessage();
    idFromWorldService = greeterReply.getId();
    logger.info("Response from WorldService  -- {}, id = {}", messageFromWorldService, idFromWorldService);
} catch (StatusRuntimeException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    logger.warn("Exception when calling WorldService\n" +  e);
}

//Call TeamService
ManagedChannel teamChannel = getChannel("localhost:8082", "helloService-team-client");
TeamServiceGrpc.TeamServiceBlockingStub teamServiceStub = TeamServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(teamChannel);
TeamCommand teamCommand = new TeamCommand(greeterRequest, teamServiceStub);

String messageFromTeamService = "";
String idFromTeamService = "";
try {
    Greeter.GreeterReply greeterReply = teamCommand.construct().toBlocking().toFuture().get();
    messageFromTeamService = greeterReply.getMessage();
    idFromTeamService = greeterReply.getId();
    logger.info("Response from TeamService  -- {}, id = {}", messageFromTeamService, idFromTeamService);
} catch (StatusRuntimeException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    logger.warn("Exception when calling TeamService\n" +  e);
}

assert(idFromWorldService.equals(idFromTeamService));
Greeter.GreeterReply greeterReply = Greeter.GreeterReply.newBuilder().setMessage("Hello" + messageFromWorldService + " from " + messageFromTeamService).setId(idFromWorldService).build();
responseObserver.onNext(greeterReply);
responseObserver.onCompleted();
```

PreservableContext class

```
public class PreservableContexts {

    //private final TraceContext traceContext;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PreservableContexts.class.getName());

    public PreservableContexts() {
        logger.info("Creating new PreservableContexts");
        //this.traceContext = TraceContextHolder.getContext();
    }

    public void set() {
       // if (traceContext != null) {
            //TraceContextHolder.setContext(traceContext);
       // }
    }

    public void clear() {
        //TraceContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
```

The log in PreservableContexts and CustomHystrixConcurrencyStrategy never get printed. I am registering the startegy when I start the HelloServer.

```
HystrixConcurrencyStrategy strategy = new CustomHystrixConcurrencyStrategy();
        HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerConcurrencyStrategy(strategy);
        context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
```

**EDIT 2**

Updated how the Observables are set up:

```
    ManagedChannel worldChannel = getChannel("localhost:8081", "helloService-world-client");
    //Async stub instead of blockingStub
    WorldServiceGrpc.WorldServiceStub worldServiceStub = WorldServiceGrpc.newStub(worldChannel);
    WorldCommand worldCommand = new WorldCommand(greeterRequest, worldServiceStub);

    //Call TeamService
    ManagedChannel teamChannel = getChannel("localhost:8082", "helloService-team-client");
    TeamServiceGrpc.TeamServiceStub teamServiceStub = TeamServiceGrpc.newStub(teamChannel);
    //TeamServiceGrpc.TeamServiceBlockingStub teamServiceStub = TeamServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(teamChannel);
    TeamCommand teamCommand = new TeamCommand(greeterRequest, teamServiceStub);

    try {
        rx.Observable<Greeter.GreeterReply> worldReplyObservable = worldCommand.observe().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
        rx.Observable<Greeter.GreeterReply> teamReplyObservable = teamCommand.observe().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
        Observable.zip(worldReplyObservable, teamReplyObservable, new Func2<Greeter.GreeterReply, Greeter.GreeterReply, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Greeter.GreeterReply worldReply, Greeter.GreeterReply teamReply) {
                String messageFromWorldService = worldReply.getMessage();
                String idFromWorldService = worldReply.getId();
                logger.info("Response from WorldService  -- {}, id = {}", messageFromWorldService, idFromWorldService);

                String messageFromTeamService = teamReply.getMessage();
                String idFromTeamService = teamReply.getId();
                logger.info("Response from TeamService  -- {}, id = {}", messageFromTeamService, idFromTeamService);

                assert(idFromWorldService.equals(idFromTeamService));
                Greeter.GreeterReply greeterReply = Greeter.GreeterReply.newBuilder().setMessage("Hello" + messageFromWorldService + " from " + messageFromTeamService).setId(idFromWorldService).build();
                logger.info("Final response=" + greeterReply.getMessage());
                responseObserver.onNext(greeterReply);
                responseObserver.onCompleted();
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
        logger.warn("Exception when calling WorldService and/or TeamService\n" +  e);
    }
```

I have a weird problem now, the calls to TeamCommand and WorldCommand doesn't complete as in this code is never executed:

```
Observable.zip(worldReplyObservable, teamReplyObservable, new Func2<Greeter.GreeterReply, Greeter.GreeterReply, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object call(Greeter.GreeterReply worldReply, Greeter.GreeterReply teamReply) {
                    String messageFromWorldService = worldReply.getMessage();
```

Also, if there is a fallback, the hystrix-timer threads doesn't have the MDC anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much knowledge with hysterix, but if you are trying to pass some contextual info like trace IDs around, then io.grpc.Context is the correct class to use. You would need to call `context.withValue` to create a new context with the traceID. In the places where you want the data, you need to attach the context. Also be sure to detach the context when done, which I do not see happening in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ...

`HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerConcurrencyStrategy(...)`

... to register a custom `HystrixConcurrencyStrategy` that uses your own `Callable` ...

```
public class ConcurrencyStrategy extends HystrixConcurrencyStrategy {    
    @Override
    public <K> Callable<K> wrapCallable(Callable<K> c) {
        return new ContextCallable<>(c);
    }
}
```

... that applies context preservation around the circuit ...

```
public class ContextCallable<K> implements Callable<K> {

    private final Callable<K> callable;
    private final PreservableContexts contexts;

    public ContextCallable(Callable<K> actual) {
        this.callable = actual;
        this.contexts = new PreservableContexts();
    }

    @Override
    public K call() throws Exception {
        contexts.set();
        try {
            return callable.call();
        } finally {
            contexts.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

... via is a helper class capable of preserving the Zipkin context ...

```
public class PreservableContexts {

    private final TraceContext traceContext;

    public PreservableContexts() {
        this.traceContext = TraceContextHolder.getContext();
    }

    public void set() {
        if (traceContext != null) {
            TraceContextHolder.setContext(traceContext);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        TraceContextHolder.clearContext();
    }

}
```

... and allowing an easy method of adding other contexts you may wish to preserve e.g. MDC, SecurityContext etc ...

Comment: I created a custom ConcurrentStrategy class and added logs to check that it is being called but no logs get printed. I edited the question since it's difficult to format it nicely in a comment. Any ideas? Also, the Javadoc of HystrixConcurrenyStrategy mention it's use with HystrixCommand and not HystrixObservableCommand - 
``` For example, every Callable executed by HystrixCommand will call wrapCallable(Callable) to give a chance for custom implementations to decorate the Callable with additional behavior.
``` 
Does the custom ConcurrentStrategy work for both?

Comment: Assuming you use the [Thread Isolation Strategy](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#threads--thread-pools) then the [Concurrency Strategy](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Plugins#concurrencystrategy) should be applied ... Im not sure about Semaphore Isolation but it doesn't look like you are opting for that anyway.

I've just tested this locally and Observable commands do trigger the plugin.

I think the problem you have is how you are invoking the Commands. Instead of `teamCommand.construct()` try `teamCommand.execute()` or `teamCommand.queue()`.

Comment: Instructions for [Synchronous Execution](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#synchronous-execution) and [Asynchronous Execution](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#asynchronous-execution) can be found on the [How To Use](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use) page.

Comment: Thanks Mike, after the change the custom concurrency strategy is getting called. I would actually need Semaphore isolation too eventually. I changed the code and updated the question. So now, the calls never come back and the fallback logs do not have the MDC. The calls do get executed and have the MDC I would like.

Comment: I think we are getting off the topic of the original post now. It might be time to mark the original question as answered and raise a separate question.

However, a quick glance would suggest to me that you need to subscribe to the object returned by `Observable.zip(...)`.

Comment: I agree on the Observable.zip part but the HystrixConcurrency strategy is still not getting applied to the HystrixTimer threads which is what the fallbacks are getting called on.